# Remove invalid parenthesis - JS (Leetcode301)

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I've been taking leetcode challenges and come across this interesting problem: [301. Remove Invalid Parentheses](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-invalid-parentheses/):

> Given a string `s` that contains parentheses and letters, remove the minimum number of invalid parentheses to make the input string valid.
>
> Return *all the possible results*. You may return the answer in **any order**.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: s = "()())()"
> Output: ["(())()","()()()"]
> ```
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> ```
> Input: s = "(a)())()"
> Output: ["(a())()","(a)()()"]
> ```
>
> #### Example 3:
>
> ```
> Input: s = ")("
> Output: [""]
> ```
>
> ### Constraints:
>
> - `1 <= s.length <= 25`
> - `s` consists of lowercase English letters and parentheses `'('` and `')'`.
> - There will be at most 20 parentheses in `s`.

I tried to solve it using recursion, but something is not right about my code, it's returning an empty array instead of the results.

Here is the code:

```
var removeInvalidParentheses = function(s) {
  const validExpressions = [];
  let minimumRemoved = 0;
  function recurse(s, index, leftCount, rightCount, expression, removedCount) {
    let possibleAnswer;    
    if (index === s.length) {
      if (leftCount === rightCount) {
        if (removedCount <= minimumRemoved) {
          possibleAnswer = expression.join("");
          if (removedCount < minimumRemoved) {
            validExpressions.length = 0;
            minimumRemoved = removedCount;
          }
          validExpressions.push(possibleAnswer);
        }
      }
    } else {
      let currentCharacter = s[index];
      let length = expression.length;
      if (currentCharacter !== '(' && currentCharacter !== ')') {
        expression.push(currentCharacter);
        recurse(s, index + 1, leftCount, rightCount, expression, removedCount);
        expression.splice(length, 1);
      } else {
        recurse(s, index + 1, leftCount, rightCount, expression, removedCount + 1);
        expression.push(currentCharacter);
        if (currentCharacter == '(') {
          recurse(s, index + 1, leftCount + 1, rightCount, expression, removedCount);
        } else if (rightCount < leftCount) {
          recurse(s, index + 1, leftCount, rightCount + 1, expression, removedCount);
        }
        expression.splice(length, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  recurse(s, 0, 0, 0, [], 0);
  return validExpressions;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you initialise `minimumRemoved = 0` which makes it impossible to ever satisfy  the condition `if (removedCount <= minimumRemoved) {` except if `removeCount` is 0. But if there is no match in that condition, nothing will be ever pushed to `validExpressions`.

You'll want to mimic the *worst* situation possible, so that any solution will be considered to be better than that. Therefore initialise `removedCount` as a high number, like `s.length + 1` or -- why not -- `Infinity`.

There is a second issue in your code: it may collect duplicate values in `validExpressions`, so make your return statement like this:

```
return [...new Set(validExpressions)];
```

This will make it work. Now, this is not a very fast solution. You may want to try to find improvements.

Comment: Thanks, I just found both problems, and come here to answer my own question.
And you are right, it is indeed a very slow solution, and I do not really understand how to improve it. And I'm not sure about time complexity, but I think it must be exponential.

Comment: And my i ask, how did you formated the question like this - https://simplest-image-hosting-net.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/bfce25a6-92f1-4441-8c1b-0062c3b4fca4.jpg ???

Comment: You can click the edit link below your question and you will see the formatting codes I used. NB: the editor has some toolbar buttons to help you with such formatting.

Comment: I'll use it next time. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

The problems are correctly highlihted by trincot. Here is the final code:

```
let removeInvalidParentheses = function (s) {
    const validExpressions = [];
    let minimumRemoved = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

    function recurse(
        s,
        index,
        leftCount,
        rightCount,
        expression,
        removedCount
    ) {
        let possibleAnswer;

        // If we have reached the end of string.
        if (index === s.length) {
            // If the current expression is valid.
            if (leftCount === rightCount) {
                // If the current count of removed parentheses is <= the current minimum count
                if (removedCount <= minimumRemoved) {
                    // Convert StringBuilder to a String. This is an expensive operation.
                    // So we only perform this when needed.
                    possibleAnswer = expression.join("");

                    // If the current count beats the overall minimum we have till now
                    if (removedCount < minimumRemoved) {
                        validExpressions.length = 0;
                        minimumRemoved = removedCount;
                    }
                    validExpressions.push(possibleAnswer);
                }
            }
        } else {
            let currentCharacter = s[index];
            let length = expression.length;

            // If the current character is neither an opening bracket nor a closing one,
            // simply recurse further by adding it to the expression StringBuilder
            if (currentCharacter !== "(" && currentCharacter !== ")") {
                expression.push(currentCharacter);
                recurse(
                    s,
                    index + 1,
                    leftCount,
                    rightCount,
                    expression,
                    removedCount
                );
                expression.splice(length, 1);
            } else {
                // Recursion where we delete the current character and move forward
                recurse(
                    s,
                    index + 1,
                    leftCount,
                    rightCount,
                    expression,
                    removedCount + 1
                );
                expression.push(currentCharacter);

                // If it's an opening parenthesis, consider it and recurse
                if (currentCharacter == "(") {
                    recurse(
                        s,
                        index + 1,
                        leftCount + 1,
                        rightCount,
                        expression,
                        removedCount
                    );
                } else if (rightCount < leftCount) {
                    // For a closing parenthesis, only recurse if right < left
                    recurse(
                        s,
                        index + 1,
                        leftCount,
                        rightCount + 1,
                        expression,
                        removedCount
                    );
                }

                // Undoing the append operation for other recursions.
                expression.splice(length, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    recurse(s, 0, 0, 0, [], 0);
    return Array.from(new Set(validExpressions));
};
```